# arrange a file with sed

Tags: unix, sed

Okay I have a file which look like this :

```
>S000632122
Bacteria;domain;"Actinobacteria";Actinobacteria;Acidimicrobidae;Acidimicrobiales;order;"Acidimicrobineae";Acidimicrobiaceae;Acidimicrobium;
>S000632121
Bacteria;domain;"Actinobacteria";Actinobacteria;Acidimicrobidae;Acidimicrobiales;order;"Acidimicrobineae";Acidimicrobiaceae;Acidimicrobium;
>S000541758
Bacteria;domain;"Actinobacteria";Actinobacteria;Acidimicrobidae;Acidimicrobiales;order;"Acidimicrobineae";Acidimicrobiaceae;Acidimicrobium;
```

But I want something like this

```
>S000632122\tBacteria; domain; actinobacteria\n
>S000548245\tBacteria; domain; actinobacteria\n
```

I tried with sed but I'm a bit lost...
Here is what I've done :

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\t/g' my file
```

But it returns me that:

```
>S000632122 \tBacteria;domain;"Actinobacteria";Actinobacteria;Acidimicrobidae;Acidimicrobiales;order;"Acidimicrobineae";Acidimicrobiaceae;Acidimicrobium;\t>S000632121\tBacteria;domain;"Actinobacteria";Actinobacteria;Acidimicrobidae;Acidimicrobiales;order;"Acidimicrobineae";Acidimicrobiaceae;Acidimicrobium;\t>S000541758
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Comment: Hello: oh okay I'm sorry I'm going to edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing is almost always simpler with awk:

```
$ cat input
>S000632122
Bacteria;domain;"Actinobacteria";Actinobacteria;Acidimicrobidae;Acidimicrobiales;order;"Acidimicrobineae";Acidimicrobiaceae;Acidimicrobium;
>S000632121
Bacteria;domain;"Actinobacteria";Actinobacteria;Acidimicrobidae;Acidimicrobiales;order;"Acidimicrobineae";Acidimicrobiaceae;Acidimicrobium;
>S000541758
Bacteria;domain;"Actinobacteria";Actinobacteria;Acidimicrobidae;Acidimicrobiales;order;"Acidimicrobineae";Acidimicrobiaceae;Acidimicrobium;
$ awk '/^>S[0-9]*$/{ printf "%s\t", $0; next} {printf "%s; %s; %s\n", $1, $2, tolower($4)}' FS=\; input
>S000632122     Bacteria; domain; actinobacteria
>S000632121     Bacteria; domain; actinobacteria
>S000541758     Bacteria; domain; actinobacteria
```

It's not clear to me from the question if you actually want literal text `\t` and `\n` in the output.  If you do, you could do:

```
$ awk '/^>S[0-9]*$/{ printf "%s\\t", $0; next} {printf "%s; %s; %s\\n\n", $1, $2, tolower($4)}' FS=\; input
>S000632122\tBacteria; domain; actinobacteria\n
>S000632121\tBacteria; domain; actinobacteria\n
>S000541758\tBacteria; domain; actinobacteria\n
```

In each of these, the first clause matches the regex `^>S[0-9]*$` and prints those lines with a trailing tab.  (Removing the newline effectively joins the next line in the output.)  Every other line is printed according to the format string.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works but the line "Bacteria; domain; actinobacteria" is not the same through the file... it can be other stuff like Bacteria;"Actinobacteria";Actinobacteria;Acidimicrobidae;Acidimicrobiales;"Acidimicrobineae";Acidimicrobiaceae;Acidimicrobium;....

Comment: @LaraFarron I'm not sure I understand how that's an issue. Which field from the line do you want printed in the output?  Include those columns in the `printf` format string.

Comment: For example, when I head my file I have >S000494589
Bacteria;"Actinobacteria";Actinobacteria;Acidimicrobidae;Acidimicrobiales;"Acidimicrobineae";Acidimicrobiaceae;Acidimicrobium;
>S000632122
Bacteria;"Actinobacteria";Actinobacteria;Acidimicrobidae;Acidimicrobiales;"Acidimicrobineae";Acidimicrobiaceae;Acidimicrobium;    and When I use the code; It only give me Bacteria; domain; actinobacteria do you see what I mean ?

Comment: I dont have the end of the line

Comment: oh no it's okay, just have to replace $4 by $0 Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'N;s/\n(([^;]*;){3}).*/\t\L\1/;s/;/\n/3;s//& /g;s/"//g' file
```

Or if the tab and newline are literal:

```
sed -E 'N;s/\n(([^;]*;){3}).*/\\t\L\1/;s/;/\\n/3;s//& /g;s/"//g' file
```

Append the following line.

Replace the newline by a tab and remove all but the first 3 fields of the second line (also lowercase the second line at the same time).

Replace the 3rd `;` by a newline.

Put a space after all remaining `;`'s.

Remove any `"`'s.